# Message Send Sucessfully but after Gives an Error Message SKPSMTPMessage

Tags: iphone, xcode, smtp, ios6, xcode4.5

I am using `SKPSMTPMessage` class to send mail within the App.

The mail send successfully but after it gives error message means it firstly calls this Delegate Method of `SKPSMTPMessage`

```
- (void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message
```

Then it calls second delegate message:-

```
- (void)messageFailed:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error
```

and gives error message on console is:

```
error(555): Failed to send email
```

And I have a question in my mind why this call `messageFailed` method when message successfully sent to the receiver email id?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Reason behind these problem was In `SKPSMTPMessage` whenever email sent successfully `connectTimer` was `not stopped` and `watchdog` too was `not stopped`, As a result it was `trying to send email again`.

Before `[delegate messageSent:self];` add below line of code  in `SKPSMTPMessage.m` file, :

```
[self.connectTimer invalidate];
[self stopWatchdog];
```

**Edit** : This working for me